# Problem based on Algebraic identities

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Algebraic identities:
$$(a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2ab$$
$$(a-b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab$$
Other identities can also come to solve this question?

If $x + 1/x = 5$ and $x^2 + 1/x^3 = 8$, then what would be the value of $x^3 + 1/x^2$?

**Possible answers:**

a- 215

b- 125

c- 256

d- 525

Answer (score 3):

let $$a=x^2+\dfrac{1}{x^3},b=x^3+\dfrac{1}{x^2}$$
then $$a+b=x^2+\dfrac{1}{x^2}+x^3+\dfrac{1}{x^3}$$
and
$$x^2+\dfrac{1}{x^2}=(x+\dfrac{1}{x})^2-2=23$$
$$x^3+\dfrac{1}{x^3}=(x+\dfrac{1}{x})^3-3(x+\dfrac{1}{x})=125-15=110$$
so
$$a+b=133$$
then
$$b=133-8=125$$

Comment: The question was: Other identities can also come to solve this question?

Answer (score 2):

The premise of the question is wrong.  Neither of the two solutions of $x + 1/x = 5$ satisfy $x^2 + 1/x^3 = 8$.  Nor do they make $x^3 + 1/x^2$ equal to any of (a), (b), (c), (d).

Since "A implies B" is true whenever A is false, technically all four answers are correct.

Comment: Perhaps $x$ is an element of some mystical set we are unaware of, I propose $x$ is a duckgoose.

Comment: What algebraic identities does a "duckgoose" satisfy?

Answer (score 1):

One more useful identity is $(a + b)^3 = a^3 + 3a^2b + 3ab^2 + b^3$. The answer is 125.

Comment: the $3ab^3$ term should be $3ab^2$

Answer (score 0):

we have $x^2+1=5x$ and $x^5+1=8x^3$

$$\frac{x^5+1}{x^2}=\frac{8x^3}{x^2}=8x$$

We need to solve for $x$  from $x^2-5x+1=0$ which will satisfy  $x^5+1=8x^3$ as well

Answer (score 0):

see ($x^2$+$x^-3$)($x^3$+$x^-2$)

- =$x^5$+$x^-5$+2
- NOW x+$\frac{1}{x}$=5. FROM THIS WE GET $x^2$+$x^-2$=23 and $x^3$+$x^-3$=110
- NOW $x^5$+$x^-5$=($x^2$+$x^-2$)($x^3$+$x^-3$)$-$(x+$x^-1$)=23.110$-$5=2525
- SO($x^2$+$x^-3$)($x^3+$$x^-2$)=2525+2=2527
- so $x^3$+$x^-2$=$\frac{2527}{8}${as $x^2$+$x^-3$=8}